# Apache Velocity : is it possible to initialize many variables using one #set directive?

Tags: velocity

I'm looking for something on the lines of

```
#set($a = 0, $b = 0)
```

or

```
#set($a, $b = 0)
```

Neither of the above works.

The only alternative I can think of is to initialize an array, and refer each element by its index, but find that a bit cumbersome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to initialize several values in the same statement.

What you could do, for Velocity 2.1+, is just skip initialization and use in-place default values:

```
${a|0}
```

will render $a if it exists (or if it is the boolean value `false`), or 0 otherwise.